# how to call one match inside another match in xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

input :

firstdto:

1. link : google.com
2. name:  google

seconddto

1. link: yahoo.com
2. name: yahoo

```
<sites>
  <firstdto>
    <link>google.com</link>
    <name>google</name>
  </firstdto>
  <seconddto>
    <link>yahoo.com</link>
    <name>yahoo</name>
  </seconddto>
</sites>
```

output expected :

```
google.com
yahoo.com
google

<body>
 <link>google.com</link>
 <link>yahoo.com</link>
 <name>google</name>
</body>
```

output current:

```
google.com
google.com
google
```

Note:   I just want to import `seconddto` function inside `firstdto`. Because i want to use `seconddto` attributes inside first attributes. But i am not able to achieve that. It still gets link from `firstdto` even if i matched my template to `seconddto`.

Can someone help me with this. It would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
<Xsl:template match="/">
<head>
<style>
  .....
</style>
</head>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates select="firstdto"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="seconddto"/>
</body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="firstdto">
   <body>
     <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
       <xsl:template match="seconddto">
        <body>
          <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
        </body>
       </xsl:template>
     <xsl:value-of select="name">
   </body>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This question does not comprise a [mcve]. You didn't provide any XML. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also `xsl:template` cannot be a descendant of `xsl:template`.

Comment: @sspsujit Did you add your own code to the OP's question?

Comment: yes @michael.hor257k

Comment: I just wanted to know how to use nested template match or two template match separately in one xsl. Both method works for me @michael.hor257k

Comment: Templates cannot be nested. Please edit you question and provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to import `seconddto` function inside `firstdto`. Because i want to use `seconddto` attributes inside first attributes.

If you want to use value from `seconddto` inside `firstdto`, then you can try this:

```
<xsl:template match="/sites">
  <html>
    <head>
        <style>.....</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="firstdto"/>
    </body>
  </html>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="firstdto">
  <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="../seconddto/link"/><!-- to use/copy value from other -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to get output like:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style>.....</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <link>google.com</link>
  <link>yahoo.com</link>
  <name>google</name>
 </body>
</html>
```