# How to use two xml files inside one xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

**Input:**

First.xml(firstdto) which contains
name : google
url: gogle.com

Second.xml(secondto) which contains
name: yahoo
url: yahoo.com

**Output: Expected is**

google.com
yahoo.com
google

I mean url from first.xml, url from second.xml and name from first.xml

**what I am trying to do**:

I am trying to use second.xml values inside first.xml . I first did template match for first.xml and printed url of first.xml, inside this match i again did template match for second.xml and printed url of second.xml and closed template match for second.xml and now continues with printing name of first.xml becuase I still have scope for first.xml and closed first.xml.

can someone help me in using two template match(i.e nested template match) and extracting values based on that.

Code :

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <Xsl:template match="/">
    <body>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="firstdto"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="seconddto"/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="firstdto">
   <body>
     <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
       <xsl:template match="seconddto">
        <body>
          <xsl:value-of select="url"/>
        </body>
       </xsl:template>
     <xsl:value-of select="name">
   </body>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: How is this different from your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68945812/3016153?

Comment: Can you edit your question in order to post a well formed XML file as example of input and the corresponding output you want, please?